# Cloudera Altus Console - Integration with Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, identity-management

Cloudera Altus provides a web-based console that can be used to manage and monitor jobs. In the Altus documentation, its mentioned that one needs to have Cloudera account to access that. 
Can the user access to that console be integrated with one's own Identity Management System like Active Directory to provide more control w.r.t user governance?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - configuring the web based console can have standard LDAP or Active Directory integration, a shown here (currently at 6.2):

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/director/latest/topics/director_configure_ldap.html

You can also configure clusters built by Director to use your Kerberos / Active Directory infrastructure:

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/director/latest/topics/director_create_kerberized_cluster.html